# How to merge two folders in elevated windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, batch-rename

How would I rename a folder in Windows Command Prompt so that the contents of the folder being renamed are merged with the files already in the folder?

Both folders have a lot of files within them, so manually moving them is not an option.

I have already tried:

```
ren folder1 folder2
```

However it outputs:

```
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
```

Is there any command or batch file I can use to complete this task, without it eating two files of the same name?

---

#### **Edit**

@KenWhite has explained that commands wouldn't be able to do this, is there a batch file available that could do this?

Comment: If you mean *copy files from one folder to another, automatically renaming duplicates with a (1) or (2) like Explorer*, you can't do this from the command line. It's something Explorer provides within it's code, not part of the file copy itself.

Comment: Do you mean just copying all files from one folder into another? `copy folder1\* folder2` does this, for example, or including subdirs, `robocopy folder1 folder2 /e`.

Comment: @KenWhite Is there a batch file that could do this though?

Comment: A batch file is *from the command line*. It's just a collection of commands that you would run from the command line. No, there is no batch file that will do this, because batch files are not Explorer, and don't contain the code that Explorer does to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @KenWhite Couldn't it check the file names, and rename them as they are removed?

Comment: Sure, if you write the code to do all of those tests, calculate the proper filename, etc. There's no built-in functionality for doing so, which is what I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want to do. 


Don't use REN nor RENAME


Use **MOVE**:


DIR: folder1 folder2 folder3


C:\...\...>**mv folder1 folder2**

Results in this:

DIR: folder2 folder3

***Another example:***


***Directory a***

**DIR: a/folder1/x.txt a/folder2/x.txt**

C:\...\...>**for /L %g in (1,1,2) do mv %g/* ./**

**Result:**

**DIR a: x.txt a/folder1/ a/folder2/**


Moved x.txt from folder1 and folder2 

overrideds x.txt in folder a.